# Recycler/Listview with Youtube API for Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I have spent a couple of days learning the ins and outs of the Youtube API, but I have not found a concrete way of actually putting a youtube player inside a cardview or a list item properly. Is this even possible with the current API? I see for the player you need to extend certain things, but that doesn't really work for a recyclerview adapter. Any help would be appreciated!